# Typescript does not predict type of value inside if statement

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

How should I write the onValueChange function so that TypeScript can deduce that since `field === 'age'` `val` will be of type number?
Is there any way to achieve this (without using as number)?

```
interface IRow {
  age: number;
  name: string;
  born: Date;
  isGood: boolean;
}

const state: IRow = {
  age: 5,
  name: 'bob',
  born: new Date(),
  isGood: true
}

const onValueChange = (field: keyof IRow) => (val: IRow[keyof IRow]) => {
  if (field === 'age') {
    const someNumber = 2 * val; // The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
    state[field] = val; // Type 'string | number | boolean | Date' is not assignable to type 'number'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
  }
}

onValueChange('age')(5);
```

[image: Edit TypeScript Playground Export (forked)]

Comment: "*Why TypeScript can't deduce that since field === 'age' value will be of type number?*" because there is nothing in the code that states that. `val` is of type `string | number | boolean | Date` - it is never narrowed to anything else. So, for example for `val = false` the assignment `state["age"] = false` is wrong.

Comment: This turns out to be a near duplicate of [this question](//stackoverflow.com/q/73666445/2887218).  If `onValueChange` were not a curried function then you could make `field` and `val` pieces of a destructured discriminated union.  But you can't do that across function boundaries.  And without something like [ms/TS#27808](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) this can't be represented properly with generics either.  If I translate the answer from there to here I get [this](//tsplay.dev/NDRZ4W).  Does that address your question, or am I missing something? (Mention @jcalz to notify me)

Answer (score 0):

You can tie the type of `val` to the concrete type based on the `field` by capturing it in a generic parameter. Your code currently allows any combination of `field` and `val`. This helps calling the function correctly.

But it seems that typescript still can't figure out inside the generic code what type it actually is but you can probably safely cast to the type. E.g.

```
const onValueChange = <T extends keyof IRow>(field: T) => (val: IRow[T]) => {
  if (field === 'age') {
    const ageIsNumber = state['age']
    const ageIsAnything = state[field]

    // here val is still only string | number | boolean | Date
    // but you should be able to cast safely since calling
    // onValueChange with anything but a `number` isn't allowed
    // e.g. onValueChange('age')('4')
    const someNumber = 2 * (val as number);

    // works fine, both are IRow[T]
    state[field] = val;
  }
}
```

This might change in Typescript 4.9, there are enhancements to type narrowing in there. Edit: no change, just tried it.

Comment: Thnx for your answer Zapl. I've already tried using generics like you did but since val is not automatically deducted as a number i ended up posting the question here ^^.